# What are the current regulations to move between islands in Maldives?

Tags: covid-19, maldives

My wife and I are planning a trip in the Maldives this coming November. We are planning to stay 3 days in a hotel in Maafushi and 3 days in a resort in Thulhagiri. Is there any restriction in changing habitation to Maldives due to Covid?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will not be allowed to move between islands, you are only allowed to stay on one island for the period of stay. I doubt you will be able to visit Maafushi either as for the time being only resort islands are open for tourists.

Source:
The guidelines published on the official website - VisitMaldives.com

Comment: Note that this answer is now outdated;  ["split stays"](https://visitmaldives.s3.amazonaws.com/eJYkNEwR/pf5grgf4.jpeg) were permitted beginning August 31.

Answer (score 5):

It's allowed to travel between all tourist facilities unless they are not under monitoring.
But you have to apply for permission. It can be done by your hotel (actually, it's the only way) and free of charge. It's not a problem to get it.

More details on [Maldives Reopening Guideline](https://www.islandii.com/maldives-reopening-guideline/)

Comment: Welcome to [Travel.SE]!  This looks like an important update to the previously accepted answer, so thanks for posting it.  Note that this is what's called a ["split stay"](https://visitmaldives.com/en/covid19-updates) by the Maldives officials;  it's a new policy as of August 31, post-dating the previous answer.